# Do fractals really happen in nature?

Tags: fractals

We live in a 3 dimensional world. So, line and plane as 1 and 2 dimensional objects do not exist in reality although using these concepts are useful for modeling some problems such as motion in one direction. I have more difficulty about fractals. Although they are like 1 and 2 dimensional objects in regards that they do not happen in reality, I cannot comprehend their possible usage in modelling some problems. For 1 and 2 dimensional objects we can think of them as a limiting case of 3 dimension. For example if we keep x and y coordinate constant and just move along z direction we get the one dimensional motion. I cannot imagine such a thing for a fractal. If they are not just mathematical entities, how is it possible to use them to describe a physical phenomena in a 3 dimensional world? For example how would it be possible to walk on the edge of a fractal?

Comment: Are you aware of Mandelbrot's claim (in *The Fractal Geometry of Nature*) that fractals are *better* models for physical objects than conventional geometric figures? Certainly, as he says, clouds are not spheres.  The closer you look at them, the more complicated their boundaries appear.

Comment: "We live in a $3D$ world" is something we actually don't know. According to Einstein's general relativity we live in a $4D$ world.

Comment: One of the defining properties of a fractal is self-similarity. In the concrete, physical world there's a limit to how far down you can take that, and that is the atomic level. Apart from that, there are many things that look like fractals on _our_ scale. Coastlines are often mentioned. Break a stone, and the surface will be as close to a fractal as the rock type will allow.

Comment: @Arthur. If coastline are like fractals, why do they have integer dimension, they are one dimensional.

Comment: I think there are more than one definition of dimension. I consider dimension as the number of parameters needed to locate a point. In 3 dimension you need 3 parameter to do that.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb R$eally?

Comment: That is a problematic definition. Due to the various constructions called plane-filling and space-filling curves, you never really need more than one parameter. Ever.